If $\delta(G) \geq |T| - 1$ then $T\subseteq G$ (Proof verification)
I want to prove the following

Corollary 1.5.4. If $T$ is a tree and $G$ is any graph with $\delta(G)\geq |T| - 1$, then $T\subseteq G$.

I induct on $\delta(G)$ and wrote
Proof. Let $T'$ be a subgraph of $G$. Pick an arbitrary $v\in G$ and choose a vertex $w\in N(v)$ as the vertices of $T'$. Then if $\delta(G)=1$ let $T = T'$. Assume the statement holds for $\delta(G)<k$ for some arbitrary $k$ and consider the case when $\delta(G)=k$. By our assumption there exist a tree $T'\subseteq G$ of order $k$. Let $v'$ be a leaf in $T'$. Since $d(v')\geq k$ then at most $k-1$ vertices in the neighbourhood of $v'$ are in $T'$. Let $w'$ be the vertex in the neighbourhood of $v'$ such that $w' \not\in T'$. Then we let $T = T' + w'$. Our proof is complete.
Is this proof correct?

I think your proof is not very good. You have not explained what $T'$ is in the first and second parts of your inductive reasoning and therefore it is not clear why $G$ contains a given tree $T$.
See here
